# CSS styling of Category/Sub-Category list

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent .parent-header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  top: 36px;
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}

.child {
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.child .child-header:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}

.child:last-child .child-header:before {
  content: none;
}

.child .child-header:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h2 class="parent-header">Heading</h2>
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child-header">Block 1</h2>
    <div>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some tex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child-header">Block 2</h2>
    <div>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some tex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h2 class="child-header">Block 3</h2>
    <div>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some tex</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LmA1wsn8pLPwQCtPnqtM?p=preview

please look into the plnkr. i am trying to fill the gap between the vertical lines. can someone help me. I am open to better ways than what i did to achieve that styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/H7LTMEBRlOpm89nCMCl6?p=preview

here  is the plunker what you need.

```
.parent .parent-header:after {
  top: 35px;
}

.child-header {
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:25px;
}

.child:last-child .child-header:before {
  height: 35px;
}
```

Basically what was causing that gap was the margin from the h2.child-header. So you need to change it for a padding and then just modify the .child-header:after top value and that's all.

Hope I've been able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

add element default padding and margin 0 in you style.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding : 0;
  }
```

when you inspect your code can see default style for the element example h2

```
 h2 {
display: block;
font-size: 1.5em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

code here : https://jsfiddle.net/okvnxqxo/

Comment: what? should i not use margin and padding in my site?

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri I am not saying you shouldn't use padding and margin. I am showing what causing problem. in your code.

Comment: set a padding and margin to 0 at start and then add the value